# PouchDB update element

Tags: angularjs, put, pouchdb

i start to develop with PouchDB yesterday and i have a little problem. if I try to update an item, instead of updating the existing one, the new one is created.

my code is this

service

```
.service('LocalDB', function($q){
     var db = null;

     this.initDB = function(){
         db = new PouchDB('tutorial', {adapter: 'websql'});
     }

     this.addObject = function(object){
         return $q.when(db.put(object));
     }

     this.updateObject = function(object, params){
         params._id = object._id;
         params._rev = object._rev;

         return $q.when(db.put(params));
     }
})
```

controller code

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, LocalDB, LoginService){
       //LoginService.user have many parameters
      function initDB(){
         LocalDB.initDB();
      }
      initDB();

      $scope.addObject = function(){
          LocalDB.addObject(LoginService.user).then(function(usr){
                            LoginService.user._id = usr.id;
                            LoginService.user._rev = usr.rev;
                        },
                        function(error){ console.log(error)});
      }

      $scope.updateObject = function(){ 
           LocalDB.updateObject(LoginService.user, { following: "new" }).then(function(success){});
      }

});
```

at this point in websql table i have two distincts objects with same id but different _rev.
first object with user data and second object with following name. how do I update the first without creating a different one?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get the document with the id first to retrieve the revision id which you can then use to put the document e.g.

```
return db.get(doc._id)                             // get document with id
    .then(function(origDoc) {
        doc._rev = origDoc._rev;                   // get original revision
        return db.put(doc,doc._id,doc._rev)        // put using id and revision
           .then(function() {
               console.log("updated: " + doc._id);
            })
            .catch(function(e){
               console.log(e);
            });`
```